# How can I configure hangfire to use a none default schema in the DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have implemented Hangfire using Hangfire.MySql.Core and hangfire core.
It create default schema without `hangfire.tablename`.
I want to add prefix to add default schema of hangfire,

In following code TablesPrefix is not valid.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(
    new MySqlStorage(
        connectionString,
        new MySqlStorageOptions
        {
            TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
            JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
            DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
            TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
        }));
```

I have also installed following package still not solve.

```
Hangfire.MySqlStorage.TablesPrefixedWithSchema
```

Is Hangfire.MySql.Core support table prefix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the code or documentation indicating this is possible with MySQL.

With SQL Server you can use the SqlServerStorageOptions.SchemaName property.